# Disable JSR250 method security by Spring Boot profile

Tags: spring-boot, jsr250

I'm securing my HTTP controller endpoint methods using `@RolesAllowed` annotations, authenticated by Keycloak. Security is activated by `@EnableWebSecurity`and `@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(jsr250Enabled = true)` config annotations on a `KeycloakWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter`.

Is there a way to disable method security by profile? All the guides only show how to do it for `WebSecurity` or `HttpSecurity` ANT matchers.

Answer (score 0):

To disable Spring Security by default and enable it by activating the `enable-security` profile, disable the autoconfig beans in your `application.yml`:

```
spring:
  autoconfigure:
    exclude:
      - org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.servlet.SecurityAutoConfiguration
      - org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.security.servlet.ManagementWebSecurityAutoConfiguration
```

Then, add `@Profile("enable-security")` to your security configuration bean to disable it unless that profile is active.

Security is now disabled, but the JSR250 annotations can stay in place.